# get current page number of pdf document in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, pdf

I am trying to implement a feature where i open (suppose in iframe) a PDF file (multiple pages), Highlight a section of the document a get the page number (the one that is displayed in the PDF tool bar).
Eg: if the toolbar display 2/7 which means i am right now in page 2, i need to capture the page number information. Sounds simple but i am not able to get a .dll/function that exposes this property.

Any help would be grateful.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't think this would be possible, there's no way to control PDFs with JavaScript in the browser, which is what you'd need to do.

This article suggests the same: http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=43436.

Content of link:

> in short, no, you can't do that.
>
> really don't think JS can read properties of PDFs, since PDFs are viewed in the browser thru a plugin, ie a viewport for another application (for want of a better explanation).

You may be better trying a different route, such as generating the pages as images and implementing your own paging.  Depends on your content and requirements, of course.  ABCPDF from http://www.websupergoo.com/ is free (with a link-back), not sure if that's any help for you.